# local notification is not displayed

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios

I'm working on a Xamarion iOS app. I want to display a local notification when an event occurs in my app, Like Outlook does when an email is received.

I'm using the following code, **after having received the right to send notification from the user**, of course:

```
var content = new UNMutableNotificationContent();
if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(value: mySoundFile))
{
    content.Sound = UNNotificationSound.GetCriticalSound(mySoundFile);
}

if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(myChannelDescription))
{
    content.ThreadIdentifier = myChannelDescription;
}

content.Title = "MyTitle";
content.Body = "MyText";

var trigger = UNTimeIntervalNotificationTrigger.CreateTrigger(0.1, false);
var request = UNNotificationRequest.FromIdentifier(notification.Id.ToString(), content, trigger);

var center = UNUserNotificationCenter.Current;
center.AddNotificationRequest(request, null);
```

But the notification is not displayed.
Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

On iOS, you must request permission to use notifications before attempting to schedule them. Just like this, you can try to check if the following code is added to your project:

```
UNUserNotificationCenter.Current.RequestAuthorization(UNAuthorizationOptions.Alert, (approved, err) =>
            {
               ...
            });
```

You can change your AddNotificationRequest as follows to see if there is an error in the notification：

```
    center.AddNotificationRequest(request, (err) =>
    {
        if (err != null)
        {
            throw new Exception($"Failed to schedule notification: {err}");
        }
    });
```

For more details, you can refer to the following documents to check some permission issues:

[Enhanced User Notifications in Xamarin.iOS | Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/platform/user-notifications/enhanced-user-notifications?tabs=macos)

[Asking permission to use notifications | Apple Developer](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications/asking_permission_to_use_notifications)

**UpDate**: If your app is in the foreground. You could try implementing the delegate [userNotificationCenter(_:willPresent:withCompletionHandler:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications/unusernotificationcenterdelegate/1649518-usernotificationcenter) which will be called when a notification arrives while the app is in the foreground. Refer to the following code:

```
UNUserNotificationCenter.Current.Delegate = new TestDelegate();

public class TestDelegate: UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate
{
    public override void WillPresentNotification(UNUserNotificationCenter center, UNNotification notification,  Action<UNNotificationPresentationOptions> completionHandler)
    {
        completionHandler(UNNotificationPresentationOptions.Alert);
    }
}
```

Comment: Again, I've done this and there is no error on the call to AddNotificationRequest

Comment: I updated my answer, you can try it.

Comment: The delegate is not called at all :(

Comment: I just read the [following](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/SchedulingandHandlingLocalNotifications.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH5-SW1): "You must assign your delegate to the shared UNUserNotificationCenter object before your app or app extension finishes launching. Failure to do so may prevent your app from handling notifications correctly". I'm not doing so.

Comment: If you try to do this, will the delegate be called, and will it work if you try to increase the time interval?

Comment: I fixed it, but this does not help either.

Comment: You check whether the notification permission is turned on on the test device, go to settings->you app->notification to check whether it is turned on.

Comment: They are turned on.

Comment: I found [an official sample of a local notification](https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-forms-samples/tree/main/LocalNotifications/LocalNotifications/LocalNotifications.iOS) in Xamarin.Forms and tested that the notification can be displayed normally. It is implemented in Xamarin.iOS and called through Dependency Service. You can refer to the code in it.

Comment: I'm looking for a notification displayed by the system on the Lock Screen, not something displayed by the application.

Comment: I tested that code, and after clicking the button that notifies after ten seconds, the lock screen of the emulator will also receive a notification. You can refer to it and try it out.

Comment: This only works when the notification is scheduled, say, in 10 or more seconds. It does not work with 0.25s as seen in the samples.

Comment: Because you want to show notification on lock screen, 0.25s is not enough to show, it needs longer time interval.

Answer (score 0):

The reason for not displaying the notification could be several things. Try the following solutions:

1. Make sure that the application has the required rights to send notifications and that the user has enabled them.
2. Check if the sound file is valid and located in the application package. It may also be necessary to add it to the Info.plist file.
3. Check if the thread identifier is valid and not repeatable.
4. Check if the trigger time is valid. Setting 0.1 seconds is very short and may not be enough to display the notification.

If the above solutions do not work, it is worth using debugging tools to more closely examine why the notification is not displayed.

Comment: About the thread identifier,, what do you mean by "valid"?

Comment: The "Thread Identifier" property of a local notification is used to group related notifications together. This property is an optional string that is used to identify a group of notifications that belong to the same thread. When multiple notifications have the same thread identifier, they are grouped together in the notification center and can be presented as a single group notification.

You should use a unique string that represents the thread of notifications your app is sending.

Comment: All of the above are correct. I'll try to see if I have an error when scheduling the notification

Comment: No error while scheduling the notification. May be this is because I want to schedule it now.